# Use REGEX in R to extract specific string in value as a new column?

Tags: r, regex

I have a column that contains string of characters/values that looks like this

Current

```
111111~24-JUL-17 10:43:36~6.14
```

Desired Output

```
24-JUL-17 10:43:36
```

Hoping to take everything between the '~' --> So Date/Time and disregard everything else.

I am have this code right now but only seems to take part of it

```
df$Last <- gsub(".+\\s(.+)$", "\\1", df$col1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sub` in `base R`

```
df$c1 <- sub(".*~([^~]+)~.*", "\\1", df$c1)
df$c1
#[1] "24-JUL-17 10:43:36" "24-JUL-21 10:34:36"
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(c1 = c('111111~24-JUL-17 10:43:36~6.14',
       '111111~24-JUL-21 10:34:36~6.14'))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use tidyr's separate to get below result:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df <- data.frame(c1 = c('111111~24-JUL-17 10:43:36~6.14','111111~24-JUL-21 10:34:36~6.14'))
df
                              c1
1 111111~24-JUL-17 10:43:36~6.14
2 111111~24-JUL-21 10:34:36~6.14
df %>% separate(col = c1, into = c('x','Date','y'), sep = '~') %>% select(2)
                Date
1 24-JUL-17 10:43:36
2 24-JUL-21 10:34:36
```

Using stringr package:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% mutate(c1 = str_extract(c1, '(?<=~).*(?=~)'))
                  c1
1 24-JUL-17 10:43:36
2 24-JUL-21 10:34:36
```